# How weighing balance works and can balance itself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics, statics, stability

i am new in this community and i was not able to answer in a similar post "how does a weighing balance that has 2 identical mass on both sides is capable of balancing after being tilted".
i actually don't want to ask a question instead shear my solution to this problem.
i saw many answer to this problem but most of them didn't have a detail an throw explanation for this mechanism.

[image]

if we look at the picture above we see the weights are hold by chains that will assure the force on the beam will always be vertical, to simplify the problem we can draw an equivalent problem:

[image]

in this case if beam is tilted at **any** angel the beam will not shift to the horizontal form unless an exterior force is presented.

[image]

if we look at the force diagram the beam is still perfectly balanced in a "tilted position"
the reason the beam keeps it balance in **all** angles its because the center of mass of the whole system is located on the pivot point.
You can verify this by looking in a book of "statics of a rigid bodies", when a shape is hold in its center of mass it can be pivot to any position and still be balanced:

[image]

if we look at the sketch above we can see that body can be positioned at any orientation and be still perfectly balance, the body is hanged on its center of mass.

So how does the weighing balance is capable of balancing itself when the weight on both sides are the same?

you are probably can guess that is simple by moving the pivot point away from the center of mass

[image]

if you look close at a weighing balance you will notice the axis is located above from the point were the weights are hanging. this shift enables the beam to balance itself when tilted:

[image]

you can preform a force diagram on the beam adding the new distance d to see that the body is not balance, an easy way to see it  is by looking at the center of mass in respect to the axis:

[image]

the center of mass is at a "r" distance from the pivot point therefore it can apply torque to return to the balanced position.

i hope my explanation was clear, would like to hear your comments.

Comment: While yours is a nice presentation, this website is a **Q&A site**, not a discussion forum or a chat room. Comment sections are expected to be kept brief.